# Internal Server Error with linking database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that I want to use to make an array for an app I'm working on in Xcode. I'm following a tutorial I found on the internet [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app), and I followed the instructions, but my page is displaying an Internal Server Error. I am assuming that I didn't correctly change the info in the following code. Also, my web host uses MYSQL not MYSQLite, so I'm not sure what to change the "new mysqli" to in the code. For obvious reasons I omitted the database info. The database has one table named "descriptions" and the columns are labeled 1-50 with different values assigned.

```
<?php

class RedeemAPI {
    private $db;

    // Constructor - open DB connection
    function __construct() {
        $this->db = new mysqli('hostname', 'Username', 'Pass', 'Database Name');
        $this->db->autocommit(FALSE);
    }

    // Destructor - close DB connection
    function __destruct() {
        $this->db->close();
    }

    // Main method to redeem a code
    function redeem() {
        // Print all codes in database
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT 1 FROM descriptions');
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($1);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            echo "$1";
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
}

// This is the first thing that gets called when this page is loaded
// Creates a new instance of the RedeemAPI class and calls the redeem method
$api = new RedeemAPI;
$api->redeem();

?>
```

Comment: mysqli _is_ for mysql databases. Ref: http://us.php.net/mysqli

Comment: "MYSQL not MYSQLite" ?? MySQLite does not exist. I assume you mean it doesn't have the MySQLi extension? In that case you're using a very old PHP version, and my very strong suggestion would be to switch hosts; this one uses outdated technology (they mysql (NOT MySQLi!!) extension has been deprecated for quite a while now and should NOT be used)

Comment: Check your server logs. It'll be important to know what the actual error is

Comment: Also, it's probably due to your server configuration that PHP errors are not shown, but rather hidden in the server logs somewhere. If you can't access those: again, switch to a different host :)

Comment: @Tularis - he probably means SQLite, commonly used in iOS apps.

Comment: @KaiQing I understand, but it just arrives out of the blue, since he mentions "it does not have SQLite" while noone's talking about SQLite, nor does his code show anything SQLite-related.

Comment: @Tularis Sorry, I was confused with SQLite, and I use FatCow hosting (I regret it). My scripted language error log is empty, I don't think regular error logs exists on my account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP variables must start with a letter or `_`, so your error stems from this statement:

```
$stmt->bind_result($1);
```

Change the variable name to something like $col1, or whatever is meaningful.

Also, your `select` statement will return a single value: 1. You probably mean to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM descriptions
```

Two other points:

- You shouldn't disable autocommit unless you intend to use transactions.
- There's no need to prepare statements with simple queries that don't include untrusted input. You can just use $this->db->query("...")'. You'd need to tweak the other statements to match if you change this.

Comment: I have no idea what I'm doing with PHP. I don't know what transactions are, would I need them? and if I change the code to "$this->db->query" what else do I need to change?

Comment: @user3272893 A transaction is a method of grouping SQL queries together so that all results are applied, or none are. It ensure data integrity if you have to make several changes at once. You won't need them for most applications and certainly not for simple SELECT queries. For prepared statements, I'd leave your code alone if you don't know what you're doing, but I recommend you find a couple of other `mysqli` tutorials and compare.

Answer (score 0):

That internal server error 500 is probably masking some lovely error messages that may help. Switch your debugging on in your php.ini / php5.ini

Add this to your php.ini / php5.ini or just add one of these files to the root of your website should do the trick

```
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
error_reporting = -1
```

Second, if your host is not running MYSQLi, then they are running REALLY old php as MYSQLi is standard in php4.1.3 and above

Third, that SQL statement.. its it just some kind of rough example or is that your actual statement? If you are trying to pull off one record it should be

```
SELECT * FROM tablename.description LIMIT 1
```

Always best to make your statements very thorough